# Cannot implement ValidatorFn interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to implement a custom Cross-field validator using the `ValidatorFn` interface from Angular.

This is my code: (I followed the provided steps on https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation)

```
import { ValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

/**
* This validator implements the ValidatorFn Interface from Angular. 
* 
* @param formGroup- the FormGroup that needs Validation
* 
* @returns null if the form is valid, else some {@link ValidatorErrors}
*/
export const CompleteBloodpressureValidator: ValidatorFn = (formGroup: FormGroup) => {

    const bloodpressureSys = formGroup.get("bloodPressureSysFormControl");
    const bloodpressureDia = formGroup.get("bloodPressureDiaFormControl");

    if (bloodpressureSys != null && bloodpressureDia == null || bloodpressureSys == null && bloodpressureDia != null){
        // return some custom ValidatorErrors
        return {
            bloodPressureIncomplete: true
        };
    }
    // if everything is fine, return null
    return null;
 }
```

But the angular compiler keeps telling me the following:

```
Type '(fromGroup: FormGroup) => { bloodPressureIncomplete: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.

Types of parameters 'fromGroup' and 'control' are incompatible.

Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.ts(2322)
```

This doesn't make any sense in my opinion, my implementation of `ValidatorFn` is exactly how it should look like.

Any advice what I do wrong here?

Comment: Do you know which version of Typescript which is being used?

Comment: no idea. I just replaced formGroup: FormGroup with formGroup: AbstractControl, and now the compiler is not complaining anymore. But FormGroup extends AbstractControl, so I really don't get the problem here :(

Comment: Above snippet looks like to be working on the the newest version of Typescript so I suspect it only was failed on the older versions

Comment: How do I update the version of TypeScript in my project?

Comment: Try to look at your deps in `package.json`

Comment: okay I already looked in there and searched for the word typescript, but did not find anything. But I guess I have to take a deeper look. Thanks anyway.

The problem is really weird though because this basically means that there is something heavily wrong with inheritance in TypeScript

Comment: That's why they continue to update/fix bugs constantly :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the answer to this question is to update the TypeScript version or exchange

```
formGroup: FormGroup
```

with

```
formGroup: AbstractControl
```

It seems to be caused by a bug in the TypeScript version.

EDIT: updating to the newest TypeScript version does not change anything. I guess this is maybe a fault in the Angular Documentatation.

Comment: FormGroup IS A instance of AbstractControl, because FormGroup extends AbstractControl. Most basic inheritance. 
Also, I already pasted this link in my initial post, which shows that using FormGroup should be fine:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms

Comment: Then maybe it has something to do with the Angular version. I'm still using Angular 9 and cannot upgrade at the moment, and I still had the same error when updating the used typescript version.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Angular 12 project with TypeScript `4.3.5` and strict mode, the only option to operate with `FormGroup` is indeed using `formGroup: AbstractControl`, and then `formGroup as FormGroup` whenever `FormGroup` field or method is going to be used, e.g. `(formGroup as FormGroup).controls`.

Comment: Using Angular 17, in the tsconfig.json, if you change this: "strict": false, (to false) it will work.  Although I don't know how the change will effect on the overall app.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I copied one similar solution from one project with Angular 9 and TypeScript 3.8.3 to another with Angular 12 and TypeScript 4.2.3. TypeScript didn't complain about this in the 3.8.3 version. But gives me the same message you are receiving in the newer version.

You can check your TypeScript version in the `package.json` file:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
```

I'm not sure, but perhaps the error message TypeScript is giving to you is correct.

The `ValidatorFn` interface expects one `AbstractControl` object.

`FormGroup` extends `AbstractControl`.

You can call this interface passing one `FormGroup` object, because `FormGroup` is an `AbstractControl` object.

But, from the interface perspective, the `AbstractControl` isn't necessarily one `FormGroup`. It could be downcasted into another object, so if you expect one `FormGroup` you could have a runtime error.

#### ValidatorFn interface

```
export declare interface ValidatorFn {
    (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null;
}
```

#### FormGroup interface

```
export declare class FormGroup extends AbstractControl {
...
}
```

## EDIT - add one Java example for inheritance

I don't know TypeScript much. But on Java, this situation wouldn't compile:

```java
public class InheritanceTest implements Test {

    @Override
    public void inheritance(Vehicle vehicle) {      
    }

    // Compilation error because Vehicle isn't necessarily a Car
    // It could be a MotorCycle for instance
    // @Override
    // public void inheritance(Car vehicle) {        
    // }

}

interface Vehicle {
}

interface Car extends Vehicle {
}

interface MotorCycle extends Vehicle {    
}

interface Test {
    void inheritance(Vehicle vehicle);
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't make sense to me, because that's what inheritance is for. And also, Google mentions the exact same implementation technique in their angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation)

Comment: I see your point. In the link you passed, the "identityRevealedValidator" receives an AbstractControl object, but then the tutorial says "The validator retrieves the child controls by calling the FormGroup's get method, then compares the values of the name and alterEgo controls." It's a bit strange because, although, it states you must declare an AbstractControl on the parameter, you can assume that it is one FormGroup.

Comment: Concerning the inheritance concept, I added one example using Java, but I'm not sure if this inheritance concept is universal. Anyway, I also adopted your solution of just changing the FormGroup parameter to AbstractControl. Thanks for sharing your solution.